# How to decode url-encoded string in javascript

Tags: javascript, url-encoding

I use javascript / jquery to fill dom elements that contain umlauts:

```
var text1 = "Unser platonisches Internetreich droht in die H%E4nde einer bewaffneten Miliz zu fallen."

$("#quote1 span").html(unescape(text1));
```

How can I get rid of the url encoding e.g. "H%E4nde" and use "Hände" instead? I tried

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But none of them seem to work...

Thanks for help.

Comment: That's not "UTF-8 codes". Why is the data encoded this way?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I just want to save text in a string and then send it to an dom element. The only way I found was to put in the escape sequences manually and then use unescape.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That is not UTF-8, that is [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) also known as url encoding.

You can use [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to convert it back before displaying it

`$("#quote1 span").html(decodeURIComponent(text1));`

Answer (score 21):

Use either of the following built in JavaScript function to decode any encoded text. No need for jquery  or any other library.

```
const text1 = "Unser platonisches Internetreich droht in die H%E4nde einer bewaffneten Miliz zu fallen."

console.log(decodeURI(text1))

console.log(decodeURIComponent(text1))
```

update:
In case you're wondering how to encode, decoded text, you can use another built in JavaScript function like so

```
console.log(encodeURI(text1))

console.log(encodeURIComponent(text1))
```

Comment: This answer can be improved by sharing the conditions under which one might want to use one decoder over the other.