# Know if something in a string is in an Array or Object Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm doing something to convert the HTML Special Chars into UTF-8 Chars.
I tried a few things, but nothing worked.

I have to approaches for solving this problem, I have an js object :

```
let HTMLCharsObject = {
    "&quot;": '"',
    "&amp;": "&",
    "&euro;": "€",
    "&lt;": "<"
}
```

For exemple, in HTML Chars, `"` is equal to `&quot;` and I want to convert `&quot;` to `"`

But I also have to arrays :

```
let HTMLArray = [
    "&quot;",
    "&amp;",
    "&euro;",
    "&lt;"
]


let UTF8Array = [
    '"',
    "&",
    "€",
    "<"
]
```

And here, the elements are in the same order as the HTMLCharsObject but in separate arrays.
So, you can use what you want.

And here's the exemple string:

```
let string = "This is a &quot; test &amp;"
```

And as result i'm trying to have `"This is a " test &"`

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode url-encoded string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645224/how-to-decode-url-encoded-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly making use of your provided data:

```js
let HTMLCharsObject = {
    "&quot;": '"',
    "&amp;": "&",
    "&euro;": "€",
    "&lt;": "<"
}

let UTF8Array = [
    '"',
    "&",
    "€",
    "<"
]

let string = "This is a &quot;...&quot; test &amp;"

let result = string;
for (const [escaped, utf8] of Object.entries(HTMLCharsObject)) {
    // If you have String.prototype.replaceAll
    //result = result.replaceAll(escaped, utf8);
    // Otherwise this:
    let newResult = result.replace(escaped, utf8);
    while (newResult !== result) {
        result = newResult;
        newResult = newResult.replace(escaped, utf8);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

If you just want to decode URL encoded characters:

```js
decodeURIComponent(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hacky to do this in JavaScript, just use one of these methods

[HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

The easiest way without using frameworks

http://jsfiddle.net/k65s3/

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```