# url encode making routing prblems

Tags: javascript, angular, url, urlencode, breadcrumbs

im working on angular project and im using breadcrumbs to navigate between the pages, and i get the path decoded from the api like this
**gamme_utilitaire.php?marque=CITROEN,**
the problem here is the browser(chrome)coded the path automatcally due to Percent-encoding or url encode and change it to this
**"http://localhost:4200/gamme_utilitaire.php%3Fmarque%3DCITROEN"**
and here is the issue the breadcrumbs didn't recognise the path cause of this changes(encoding url) , im searching for a solution how to keep the url decoded in the browser..

thanks to all

Comment: You can refer to this answer which solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645261/9839202

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript URL Decode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function)